# How do I close a browser tab when the scrollbar reaches the bottom of the page?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Using **Autohotkey**, I’ve remapped a button to execute a loop.
Every 30 seconds, **PgDn** will execute.
In order to move on to the next tab, **Ctrl-W (close tab)** needs to happen.
Is there way any to detect that the scrollbar as at the bottom?
Once the **“scrollbar-at-bottom”** **condition** is met, PgDn will execute “close tab” instead.
What language should I learn to make a program/script that can do this?
I know a little bit of Java.
Can Javascript do this?

Thanks

Comment: AHHHH! Long Title! Make it Stop!

Comment: I thought there was a title length limit!! UserVoice...

Comment: I edited the title.  I think all the relevant information is contained in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to investigate [building a Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension).

Comment: *extension*. "Plugin" in mozilla refers to flash/silverlight-like components.

Comment: thanks Dave
something like this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/scrollbar
was what I was looking for
if curpos 100 (scroll position at bottom), closeTab or moveToNextTab
I can't find something that closes the tab, but I'm sure it's in there somewhere